# pass values or data from one page to another when you use Login control in ASP.NET 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-2.0

I am using Login Control available in ASP.NET 2.0 in the login page. Once the user is authenticated successfully against database, I am redirecting the user to home.aspx. Here, I want to pass on the User's name too to the home.aspx so that the user will be greeted with his/her name in the home.aspx. Ex: Welcome Smith

I am extracting the User's name from the users table in my database during the time I check for the login credentials.

Could someone please tell me how to do this in a secure way (may be not to secure, but a little)?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One good place for that kind of data would be in session.  Try something like this on the first page:

```
this.Session["UserName"] = userName;
```

and then subsequent pages in that session for that user could access `this.Session["UserName"]`.

The best thing to do though is to create a static class to manage `Session` for you like so:

```
using System;
using System.Web;

static class SessionManager
{
    public static String UserName
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"].ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"] = value;
        }
    }

        // add other properties as needed
}
```

Then your application can access session state like this:

```
SessionManager.UserName
```

This will give you maximum flexibility and scalability moving forward.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I appreciate your time and detailed explanation. I will try it. 1 question. In my situation, the user enters with email & password and when I check those values against database, I get the username from the table and want to use that in the rest of the application. How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using standard asp.net authentication then you should be able to access the users name through the User property of the page object.

User.Identity.Name

As Andrew suggested, Session is a common place to place a user name, though I avoid using session at all if possible.

You could set a cookie with the users name.

You could also set the DestinationPageUrl property of the login control to include the username in the query string.  Though that feels/looks pretty lame.

Comment: Thanks ScottS.But I don't know how to use Cookie for that.The username textbox in Login control takes email address rather than a username.And I need to get user name from database based on the credentials in Login control.

Comment: You can set a cookie using

Request.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("cookieName", "value"));

and later read the cookie using

string value = Request.Cookies["cookieName"].Value;

Answer (score 1):

As [ScottS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620134/pass-values-or-data-from-one-page-to-another-when-you-use-login-control-in-asp-ne/620177#620177) said, if you're using the standard login controls and a membership provider this information is already available to you in User.Identity.Name.

The only reason I'm posting an answer is to mention the [LoginName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginname.aspx) control, which you can drop on a page/master page and have this done automatically for you:

```
<asp:LoginName id="LoginName1" runat="server" FormatString ="Welcome, {0}" />
```

This will render out "Welcome, Zhaph" when the user is logged in, or nothing if they are not.

You can also combine this quite nicely with the [LoginView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginview.aspx) and [LoginStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginstatus.aspx) controls:

```
<asp:LoginView ID="RegisterLink" runat="server">
  <AnonymousTemplate>
    <div class="titleRegistration">
      <a href="/Users/Register.aspx">Register</a> or 
    </div>
  </AnonymousTemplate>
  <LoggedInTemplate>
    <div class="titleRegistration">
      Welcome back
        <asp:LoginName ID="LoginName1" runat="server" /> -
    </div>
  </LoggedInTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
<asp:LoginStatus ID="lsGeneral" runat="server"
  LogoutPageUrl="/Users/Logout.aspx" />
```

This combination of controls will do the following:

1. If the user isn't logged in display: Register or Login
2. If the user is logged in display: Welcome back Zhaph - Logout

The Login links is populated by the settings in web.config, and generated by the LoginStatus control.

Comment: Thanks Zhaph.The username textbox in Login control takes email address rather than a username.And I need to get user name from database based on the credentials in Login control.Any idea how to do in such a case?

Comment: Ah, I see your problem there. This is of course a limitation of using the built in controls - they aren't always as flexible as you'd like. In which case, either pop it in session, or possibly look at adding it as a property on the profile: http://bit.ly/AzSQy

Answer (score 0):

yes as Andrew said, session is the primary place to store sensitive data.

but why a user's name is sensitive ? You can save it in cookie and print it in your home.aspx whenever user comes in.

**EDIT :** You can use cookies in ASP.NET like that :

```
// Setting cookie : 
Response.Cookies["UserName"].Value = "Erhan";
Response.Cookies["UserName"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7); // Persists 1 week

// Getting cookie : 
string username = string.Empty;
if(Request.Cookies["UserName"] != null)
{
    username = Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies["UserName"].Value);
}
```

**NOTE :** Cookies stored at client's machine. so you should not use them to store sensitive data.

Comment: You are right. But honestly, I am a real novice and would like to know how to use a cookie to do that? And also would like to know which is the best way performance wise. Thanks so much.