# How to get a UserId from one page and pass to another

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been trying to work on a project using asp.net.
In this project I will create a page where user can edit his profile and that is what is killing me.
I'm kinda new to programming in general, what I need is to get the userID from the current logged user, and fill some info on the page using his ID. Then, add a edit control, that will redirect him to a edit page with all information already avaliable from that user on the other page. Can someone tell me how to do that? And sorry about my english, its not my native language.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are using `forms auth`, you can store the user ID in the cookie `userData` for later re-use, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationticket.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping data on the server side that is user specific is usually done using sessions. Check this out: [pass values or data from one page to another when you use Login control in ASP.NET 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620134/pass-values-or-data-from-one-page-to-another-when-you-use-login-control-in-asp-n?rq=1)